# Custom UINavigationBar sizeThatFits implementation not returning real frame.size.width

Tags: ios, resize, ios6, uinavigationbar, subclassing

I am trying to subclass `UINavigationBar` with a defined height and trying to implement `sizeThatFits` method:

```
@implementation NavigationBar

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    NSLog(@"frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
    return CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 62);
}

@end
```

But apparently the `self.frame.size.width` is always returning a weird value which isn't 1024 which is what I am aiming for and it is causing the behaviour presented below:

[image]

`NSLog` output:

```
> frame: {{224, 20}, {576, 62}}
```

While manually defining `CGSizeMake(1024, 62)` this will cause the following:

[image]

hiding the buttons and the `NSLog` output will be:

```
> frame: {{-128, 20}, {1280, 62}}
```

Any idea on how to properly implement this method so the navigation bar extends across all window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `layoutSubviews` and `sizeThatFits` together seems to work:

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    return CGSizeMake(1024, 62);
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 1024, 64);
}
```

Comment: Hi Liam, I have tried that before. `layoutSubview` won't take the navigationBar height into account and it will simply overlay the content below the bar instead of applying the correct space.

Comment: thanks Liam, I think I found something that may have worked, but only because of your initial help :), if you are happy with it you can edit  your answer and I will mark it as correct. What I have done was this (http://pastebin.com/X5svpW7s). So I had to implement both methods. cheers

Answer (score 9):

If you want to avoid using "magic numbers", use could try to use `UINavigationBar` superview's size.

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
    return CGSizeMake(self.superview.bounds.size.width, 62.0f);
}
```

Works well for me on iOS 6. No need to override `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: What needs to be added for this to work when orientation changes?

Comment: @RandyHunt It seems nothing is required. iOS queries for this size on rotations automatically.

Comment: Thus, call `[super sizeThatFits:size]; return self.superview.bounds.size;` ?!